# Maven remote settings.xml file

Tags: maven

Is it possible to specify a remote settings.xml file for maven to use?

So it could be convenient to update one settings.xml file in some remote location (server), and the rest of the dev team wouldn't have to download it manualy.

Comment: Why do you need to update the settings.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite likely you could do this using tricks outside maven itself, such as symlinking or, as mentioned before me, sharing them through a repository.

But you probably should not. The settings.xml file is used for *local* settings - specific to your machine. You use this for example to specify the location of your local application server or a local database connection, etc. You would have to force every user to use the same file system layout and server setup, which probably requires more hassle than a shared settings.xml would save.

The proper way to share settings across a project is to include them in the project's pom. If you want to share across a team or organisation regardless of project, you can use a parent pom, or even several layers of them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer no, cause the `settings.xml` defines the configuration to access remote resources furthermore it could contain passwords/keys etc. which would not make sense to store remotely.

You can create a git repository which contains `${HOME}/.m2/` included the settings.xml as a template so the onboarding is simpler.